# In Swift, how do you check if pointer in Parse column is empty or not

Tags: swift, parse-platform

Within my user object I added a column to add a users favorite team. The column is identified as favTeam and is a pointer to a teams class

Here is my code. I have populated my user with a favorite team however the logic is always showing that "favteam nil"

```
    if let object = PFUser.currentUser()!["favTeam"] as? [PFObject]{
        print("favteam not nil")
        print(object)
        let favTeam = PFUser.currentUser()!["favTeam"]
        favTeamText.text = favTeam["Name"] as? String
        if let favTeamImageView = favTeam["teamLogo"] as? PFFile {
            favTeamImageView.getDataInBackgroundWithBlock { (imageData: NSData?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
                if error == nil {
                    if let imageData = imageData {
                        self.teamLogo.image = UIImage(data: imageData)

                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    else {
        print("favteam nil")
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I can accomplish this by using a PFUser.query() as follows...

```
func fetchFavoriteTeam() {
let userQuery: PFQuery = PFUser.query()!

userQuery.whereKey("username", equalTo: (currentUser?.username)!)
userQuery.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock({
    (users, error) -> Void in

    var favTeam = users!

    if error == nil {
        if favTeam != nil {
            favTeamContainer = favTeam.valueForKey("favTeam") as! PFObject
        }
    } else {
        print(error)
    }
})
```

`}`

Comment: yeah that should work...still buzzed why my code fails. I'll give it a shot!

Comment: Xcode 7.2 doesn't like `if favTeam != nil` 
"Value of type '[PFObject]' can never be nil, comparison isn't allowed"

Comment: Ah hah...I just figured out my PFUser.currentUser wasn't loaded with whats in the database. Once I set and saved it with my favTeam object, all was good.

Comment: Excellent I am glad that worked. Will you use this as your solution or are you preferring to figure out how to do it the way you've previously tried?

Comment: i actually used my previous posted way of doing it.